# How to reset the value of the dropdowns defined in a form in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a formed defined as :

```
<form id="form_details "#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"  >
```

Inside this form i have 1 dropdown and when i click on the submit button defined on the form,
I am able to get the value of the dropdown.My requirement is that i have another button in tge form which should function as reset,i.e when i click on it the dropdown should return to its default selected values.
How can this be achieved?Also when form is submitted after the reset,the form value should be all employees.(not null).

```
<form id="form_details "#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"  >
<select [(ngModel)]="emp_name" id='emp' name='emp_name'>
  <option selected>All Employees</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of employees " value= {{emp}}>
      {{emp}}
    </option> 
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: post the default value and all json of employees variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value(like 'All Employees' or 'AllEmployees' etc) to the default option also.

**.html**

```
 <form id="form_details "#form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"  >
      <select [(ngModel)]="emp_name" id='emp' name='emp_name'>
        <option selected value="All Employees">All Employees</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of employees " value= {{emp}}>
          {{emp}}
        </option> 
      </select>
    
    
      <button type="button" (click)="onReset()">Reset</button>
      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**.ts**

```
 onSubmit(value) {
    this.emp_name = value;
  }

  onReset() {
   this.emp_name = "All Employees";
  }
```

Comment: that solves my problem partially,If i do a reset and then do form submit,I am getting form values as null,but if i do simply submit,then form values come as the default all employees.if i do reset and then submit form value is null instead of all employees